# Import Swashbuckle (swagger) to 3scale ActiveDocs

Tags: swashbuckle, 3scale

We currently have our apis documented with Swashbuckle on .net (webapi), there is any way to import this documentation into 3scale ActiveDocs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3scale ActiveDocs currently supports Swagger 1.2, and we have Swagger 2.0 support in Beta and will be generally available soon.

If you are a 3scale customer please contact Support to request Beta access.

Then you will be able to upload the generated Swagger2.0 spec into our ActiveDocs.

Comment: I have swagger 2.0 enabled, I copy and pasted the definition into 3scale, and I can see the doc on the ApiDocs tab, but is not show in the developer portal. Pubhish and show are set, but is not shown in the dev portal, any idea? thanks.

Comment: Sorry I've seen so late Javier. Please email support and well take it from there with you. Then can post back any "solution" here. Thanks